# ggplot2: apply customization from variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and ggplot2. How would I go about applying a customization to multiple plots? I thought I could just store the customization in a variable but this does not work:

```
# customization <- theme_bw() + xlab("time")
x <- 1:20
y <- dnorm(x, 10, 5)
y2 <- dnorm(x, 10, 2)
p1 <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x,y)) # + customization
p2 <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x,y2)) # + customization
```

Now I would like to apply customization to both plots without copy/pasting the two additional settings.

Comment: Can you make your code easier for us to run by using sample datasets?

Comment: I changed the example since it was a bit confusing. I commented out the code which did not run. Hope this makes my question more clear to you.

Comment: I think the solution to this question is way deeper and more complicated than the effort it takes to copy and paste the customizatin. The "+" sign is a S3 method (see ggplot2:::`+.gg`)

Comment: `p2 + list(theme_bw(), xlab("time"))`

Comment: That's what I had in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `theme` elements in one object and the labels in another object and then combine them with `+`. This isn't quite as succinct as what you were probably hoping for, but maybe it gets you part of the way there. If you have more than one label and several `theme` elements, it will save you some typing. For example:

```
x <- rep(1:20,2)
y <- c(dnorm(x[1:20], 10, 5), dnorm(x[21:40], 20, 5))
group = factor(rep(c("A","B"),each=20))
dat=data.frame(x,y,group)

opt <- theme(title=element_text(size=18, colour="green"),
             axis.text=element_text(size=13, colour="black"),
             axis.title=element_text(size=15, colour="blue"),
             legend.title=element_text(colour="black")) 
lab <- labs(x="Time", y="Value", colour="Group", title="Plot Title")

ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(x,y, colour=group)) + opt + lab
```

**UPDATE:** Per @ Baptiste's comment, you can combine the `theme` and `labs` elements in a single `list` object:

```
custom <- list(opt, lab)

ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(x,y, colour=group)) + custom
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just combine it together in one plot like this:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x,y), color="red") + 
  geom_line(aes(x,y2), color="blue") + 
  theme_bw() + xlab("time")
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: That was not the point of my question but in general it is worth to consider combining plots with the same settings.